# If C# function return type is object then how to populate DataTable by It's return value

Tags: c#

I am using a function whose return type is object and it's returning some values.
Now I want to populate a DataTable. I am using

```
var result = GetAlternativeInstallReportClientInfo(userinfo);   

     private object GetAlternativeInstallReportClientInfo(List<UserSearchDetails> user)
                {
    .............
    ...........
    ............
    return finalData; 

        }
```

I am getting my all data in variable result. Now I want create a DataTable by Data which holded result (variable).  what should I do?

If I am crating my Function return type DataTable

```
DataTable data = GetAlternativeInstallReportClientInfo(userinfo);   

         private DataTable GetAlternativeInstallReportClientInfo(List<UserSearchDetails> user)
                    {
        .............
        ...........
        ............
        return finalData; 

            }
```

then getting error 
CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>' to 'System.Data.DataTable'

I want to create DataTable because I have to export records in Excel Sheet

Comment: Probably you should explain why you need a DataTable instead of a strongly typed collection of objects.

Comment: Can you change the return type of that function to be more specific?

Comment: not enough code.if it returns an object, then its an object, what type is the object? cast result to the known type.

Comment: [Everything concrete in C# is derived from `object`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object/). Your question is essentially: "I have data returned in an undisclosed type, how do I use it to populate a DataTable". I don't know how you expect an answer. For all we know object is a `string`, or a `Dictionary<TKey,TVal>`, or a `List<T>`, etc

Comment: I updated my question, please have a look

Answer (score 0):

Try this one.

```
var query= "your data...";   
DataTable dt = query.CopyToDataTable();
```

it will copy all data to datatable.
Thanks.